# Сослагательный инфинитив при союзе "чтобы" и разносубъектные конструкции

Tags: грамматика

Попалось на глаза вот такое предложение:

> Должно пройти достаточно много времени, чтобы стать мастером.

Я воспринял его как грамматически неправильное. Погуглив, нашел такое [описание](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#41) соответствующего грамматического явления:

> Во многих типах придаточных предложений при союзе *чтобы* инфинитив
>   оформляет равносубъектные конструкции, в то время как прошедшее время
>   чаще используется в разносубъектных. В
>   придаточных предложениях при союзе *чтобы*, таким образом, употребление
>   сослагательного инфинитива диктуется не семантическими, а
>   синтаксическими условиями:
>
> > (98) Старуха побежала к будке регулировщика, **чтобы остановить** поезд.
>
> Ср. употребление формы
>   прошедшего времени в разносубъектной конструкции:
>
> > (99) Старуха побежала к будке регулировщика, **чтобы** он **остановил** поезд.

Однако я не понимаю, почему предложение начинает восприниматься как правильное, если перефразировать его следующим образом:

> Нужно достаточно много времени, чтобы стать мастером.

Ведь конструкция по-прежнему разносубъектная. В чем же, с точки зрения грамматики, состоит разница между изначальным вариантом и переиначенным, делающая второй правильным?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это согласуется с правилом, которое Вы процитировали. В обоих придаточных предложениях в предложении «Нужно достаточно много времени, чтобы стать мастером» подразумевается один и тот же субъект:

> *Мне* нужно достаточно много времени, чтобы [*мне*] стать мастером.

А в предложении «Должно пройти достаточно много времени, чтобы стать мастером» субъекты разные; нельзя сказать «Мне должно пройти достаточно много времени, чтобы [мне] стать мастером».

Comment: должно пройти достаточно много времени [для меня] будет чуть правильней.

Comment: @shabunc да, но сама фраза "должно пройти достаточно много времени, чтобы стать мастером" неправильная.

Comment: Я полагаю, здесь дело в том, что в русском языке есть так называемые дательные подлежащие. Они обладают многими свойствами подлежащих в именительном падеже, например, контролируют рефлексивные местоимения и подлежащие зависимых инфинитивных конструкций.

Comment: @Olga, ну, я, повторюсь, сторонник описательного языкознания - де-факто такая конструкция встречается не так уж редко.

Comment: Кстати, про "дательные подлежащие" в гугле всего два результата поиска. Текущая страница и [вот такая статья](http://www.rus.or.kr/oldsite/study_file_down.asp?tbcode=01&filename=20100105115931%C2%B4%5E%EC%8A%AC%EB%9D%BC%EB%B8%8C25-2-%EC%B6%94%EC%84%9D%ED%9B%88.pdf).