# Чтобы X [?] сделайте Y - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Написал предложение. Инуитивно - без запятой. Потом подумал, что сложносочинённое, добавил запятую. Посмотрел - выглядит неестественно. Полез искать - и не нашёл. Зато нашёл, что часто это не считается сложным предложением вообще.

Образец: Чтобы оставаться на месте [?] бегите без остановки. Чтобы покинуть автобус [?] выбейте стекло.

Можно ли на отмеченном месте не ставить никаких знаков препинания, ни запятой, ни тире - ничего?

Тип предложения:

- Начинается со "Чтобы"
- Нет сложного союза. Не "для того чтобы", не "вместо того чтобы", и т.д.
- Нет отдельного подлежащего в основной части.
- Основная часть - побудительная.

Близкий, но другой пример - безличные предложения. Чтобы оставаться на месте [?] надо бежать без остановки. Чтобы покинуть автобус [?] надо выбить стекло.

В гугле-яндексе в основном находятся:

- обсуждение использования "для того чтобы" - не то. Например http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/911116-dlja-togo-chtoby-ili-dlja-togo-chtoby.html
- "чтобы" в середине предложения, а не первым словом.

Нашёл один пример - но и тот случайный, не по основнoй теме статьи и "безличный" вариант вместо побудительного: самое начало 1-го Задания: https://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37407.php

Здесь очень близко, но опять-таки не совсем то.

- [Сослагательный инфинитив при союзе "чтобы" и разносубъектные конструкции](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1049)
- [http://rusgram.ru/Сослагательное_наклонение](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

В общем, потерямшись мы...

Comment: I can't even picture myself doubting the fact the comma is required in your examples.

Comment: @Quassnoi what rule specifically would make it so obviously required? I have doubts this should be qualified as a compound sentence.

Comment: it doesn't work this way. The comma should be here because the habit of writing it here has developed over the centuries. The fact that someone has taken time to generalize and codify it as a rule in a textbook is the consequence, not the reason. The rule was there in the authors' minds first, the paragraphs in Lopatin's or Rosenthal's books came later. There are lots of languages in the world that don't have prescriptive rulebooks, but it doesn't mean they don't have rules.

Comment: @Quassnoi all rules are approximate and subjective, even Newtonian Laws invented by Newton. However there either is a normative language or there is not. If the former, then we can and should talk about rules. If the latter, then there can be no any mistakes in languages, because every single aspect of language becomes a matter of your or my personal whim. You might have a habit of writing корова while i may have an equally legit habit of writing карова, and we would be both correct to do it, unless we acknowledge existence of some rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex sentence with a dependent purpose clause (*сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным цели*).

As with almost any other complex sentence, the dependent clause should be isolated with a comma.

Lopatin et al., *Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации*, p. 115:

> В придаточных частях сложноподчиненного предложения используются союзы и союзные слова *будто, где, даром что, если (если... то), ибо, зачем, как будто, как только, как, какой, когда, который, кто, куда, лишь, лишь только, нежели, откуда, отчего, пока, поскольку, почему, словно, так как, так что, только что, точно, хотя, чей, чем, что, **чтобы*** и др.
>
> Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; если же придаточная часть стоит перед главной частью или после нее, то отделяется от нее запятой.

In your example:

> Чтобы оставаться на месте, бегите без остановки

, *чтобы* is a subordinating conjunction (*подчинительный союз*), and *чтобы оставаться на месте* is a dependent clause (*придаточная часть*).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно.

В приведённых случаях также можно заменить на тире.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102599/discussion-on-answer-by-alamar--x--y---).